# C++ - call Lua functions from Lua C module without custom .lib file

Tags: c++, c, lua

I have an app that uses a modified version of `Lua 5.2`. Lua is embedded in an `exe` and as far I can see (with Dependency Walker) there are no export symbols for its Lua functions. I have no sources of this app. I need to write C module for Lua to use with this app.

I successfully `require` it in the `Lua` file that this app processes, but as soon as I'm trying to call any `lua_*` function app crashes with **Access violation** error.

Is there a way to find addresses/names of embedded Lua functions and call them?

I asked app developers if I'm allowed to do this, they don't seem to care. The only thing is that modification of the app itself is prohibited.

UPD: As far as I can see, I get **Access violation** because I'm trying to use `Lua proxy lib` and it fails to pass calls to exe Lua C functions.
If I'm not using Proxy DLL, I get **Multiple VMs detected**. Any way to solve this?

My Lua C module code:

```
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32)
#  define LUA_BUILD_AS_DLL   /* for #define LUA_API __declspec(dllimport) */
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32)
#  ifdef __cplusplus
#    define MY_LUA_API   extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#  else
#    define MY_LUA_API   __declspec(dllexport)
#  endif
#else
#  define MY_LUA_API     extern "C"
#endif

using namespace std;

static int Lmytest_test(lua_State *L) {
    // Check the arguments.
    int argn = lua_gettop(L);
    if (argn != 1 || !lua_isstring(L, 1)) {
        lua_pushstring(L, "Give me one string argument please!");
        lua_error(L);
    }
    lua_pushstring(L, "Hello world!");
    return 2;
}

static const struct luaL_Reg lib[] = {
    { "test", Lmytest_test },
    { NULL, NULL }
};

MY_LUA_API int luaopen_mytest(lua_State* L) {

    printf("Before newlib\n");

#if LUA_VERSION_NUM >= 502
    luaL_newlib(L, lib);
#else
    lua_createtable(L, 0, sizeof(lib) / sizeof(lib[0]));
    luaL_register(L, NULL, lib);
#endif

    printf("After newlib\n");

    return 1;
}
```

For those who ask `what is Lua proxy lib`:

> http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaProxyDll
>
> http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaProxyDllTwo
>
> http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaProxyDllThree
>
> http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaProxyDllFour

Comment: You could write a trivial C-module `int luaopen_hello(lua_State *L) {
    printf("Hello from C!\n");
    return 0;
}` and then load it using `require("hello")`.  If it prints `Hello from C!`, you probably did something wrong in your module, if it also prints “Access violation” the author of the program has disabled loading modules.

Comment: Using your example I get no "Access violation". But if I'll attemp to call any `lua_*` function, it will crash with this message

Comment: Could You please show a working example of Your library? And wtf is "Lua proxy lib"?

Comment: Added code and links to lua proxy

Answer (score 0):

> I need to write C module for Lua to use with this app.

Well... you can't.

If their program does not export Lua's DLL interface, and it doesn't load Lua's DLL, then that means it statically linked with Lua. Unless you actually hack the executable, your DLL module will be talking to a Lua implementation that the main executable is not using. That's why you got a runtime crash; two different pieces of code talking to the same memory doesn't work out.

By statically linking to Lua, the developers of the application made it essentially impossible for users to write their own C modules for their uses of Lua without hacking the binary.

> Is there a way to find addresses/names of embedded Lua functions and call them?

Not without a decompiler or really good assembly skills. And thanks to link-time optimization, even those may fail you, since some Lua APIs may have been inlined.

Answer (score 0):

You most certainly can write a C dll and if the Lua environment is a properly compatible Lua system, then you should be able to achieve what you are looking to do. There are a number of things you need to check though:

1. Find out exactly what Lua version is running in the system you use. 
   This will let you determine what type of library you will need to compile against.

```
print( _VERSION )
```

2. Check other dll modules this Lua environment is using. Use dependency walker or similar. They should be using the luaopen_() type entry point. If this is the case, then your entry point above should be ok.
3. Check what you are passing to your methods. You *cannot* pass lightdata (pointers) between the Lua and your dll - mainly because their allocations will be in a different space. You will get access violations from this.
4. Check for any external libraries that the Lua system may be using. It is *common* that you will find a lua5.1.dll or similar. You need to be linking with this to ensure the methods you use, will be within the same application process space.

Often problems like this are more likely that the Lua implementation has been modified, and Lua bytecode and interfaces are not consistent, so very difficult to build against. 
Hope this helps.

Btw. Use dependency walker to look into exe's and dll's for available methods. Lua uses the stdcall name mangling, so they are always visible.
http://www.dependencywalker.com/